# How to calculate leftovers of each balance top-up using first in first out technique?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Imagine we have user balances. There's a table with top-up and withdrawals. Let's call it balance_updates.

| transaction_id | user_id | current_balance | amount | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 100 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | -100 |  |
| 3 | 2 | 400 | 400 |  |
| 4 | 2 | 300 | -100 |  |
| 5 | 2 | 200 | -200 |  |
| 6 | 2 | 300 | 100 |  |
| 7 | 2 | 50 | -50 |  |

What I want to get off this is a list of top-ups and their leftovers using the first in first out technique for each user.

So the result could be this

| top_up | user_id | leftover |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 50 |
| 6 | 2 | 100 |

Honestly, I struggle to turn it to SQL. Tho I know how to do it on paper. Got any ideas?

Comment: Can you please explain what "leftover" is and how you calculate it?

Comment: Also explain what "top_up" is

Comment: Explain the step-by-step derivation of results, via  paper method, for user 2. How does that user produce 2 result rows?